# Grails query association problem

Tags: java, grails, hql, criteria, grails-orm

I'm having trouble writing a query for the following domain classes:

```
class Person {
  static hasMany = [memberships: Membership]
}

class Membership {

    static belongsTo = [person: Person, group: Group]

    Date joinDate = new Date();
    Group group;
    Person person;
}

class Group {
     static hasMany = [memberships: Membership]
}
```

Basically, I want to found all persons which belongs to a list of groups (Let's say group ids are `(1,2)`. The trick here is that the person must be a member of both groups. I'd prefer a criteria query, but HQL is ok also.

Note that querying with something like `group.id in (1,2)` won't work because it can be any of the groups, not **both**.

Comment: I having a doubt on your mapping, is it right or wrong?

Comment: I think it is right, was a long long time ago...

Comment: Ok, I tried to create domains with your data but it shown some errors, anyways its fine, hope your problem is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my simple HQL approach:

```
Person.executeQuery("FROM Person x WHERE x IN (SELECT m.person from Membership m WHERE m.group = :group1) AND x IN (SELECT m.person from Membership m WHERE m.group = :group2)", [ group1: Group.get(1), group2: Group.get(2) ])
```

Cheers

Comment: By the way, it is not doable in criteria because if I query memberships association multiple times I end up with a hibernate "double association" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need a query. In the Person class, memberships is a list of Membership objects. You can find if an object is in a Collection (list) without making any query.
Something like this should do the job.

```
if(Person.memberships.contains(Membership.findByPersonAndGroup(person1,group1)) && Person.memberships.contains(Membership.findByPersonAndGroup(person1,group2))){
  ...do something...
}
```

Probably the other solution is simplier, but I think this is just another option.

Cheers

[Groovy Collections](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections)

Comment: In your example, the Person object is a class; I cannot query the class itself, I need an instance of person to check its memberships collection.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  Not sure the previous solutions are generic on the number of matched groups - in the cases so far, it's fixed at 2 I think.  Although there is probably a way to make them variable.

Another way I describe here on the grails messageboard - http://www.nabble.com/has-many-through-relationship-query---GORM--td23438096.html

Including commentary from the author, Robert Fischer, of "Grails Persistence with GORM and GSQL".

@chadsmall

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that avoids having to programmatically append subqueries to your WHERE clause:

Query:

```
SELECT count(person.id) AS numPeople, person 
FROM Person as person 
INNER JOIN 
person.memberships AS mships
WITH mships.group.id IN (:groupIds) 
GROUP BY person.id 
HAVING COUNT(person.id) = (:numOfGroupIds)
```

And some example values:

```
[
  groupIds: [8,9,439,86843]
  numOfGroupIds: 4
]
```

The part of this query up to the GROUP BY grabs all of the people who match *any* of the groups.  Then, by grouping by person and checking the number of results is equal to the number of groups in the list, you can verify that this person is a member of all of the specified groups.